# How To Permanently Close iOS Simulator (React Native)

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, react-native-ios

I've opened multiple iOS simulators (e.g. an iPhone XS and an iPhone X). Now, whenever I run `react-native run-ios`, all the simulators launch. How can I change this so only a single simulator launches when I run `react-native run-ios`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When all simulators are opened just close one by one hitting `CMD+W`. The next time you run it you should only have one.

Comment: Got it, you have to close all of them. Thanks!